# Import Pandas Does Not Work In Terminal; Works in Python Shell

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I'm having some issues with importing pandas into my iPython note book. However when I import pandas into the python shell it works.

Let's take a look at my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

churn_df = pd.read_csv('churn_data.csv')
col_names = churn_df.columns.tolist()

print "Columns names:"
print col_names

to_show = col_names[:6] + col_names[-6:]

print "/nSample data:"
churn_df[to_show.head(6)]
```

And I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3db7b32fc0b3> in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import division
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
      5 churn_df = pd.read_csv('churn_data.csv')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.pyc in <module>()
     42 import pandas.core.config_init
     43 
---> 44 from pandas.core.api import *
     45 from pandas.sparse.api import *
     46 from pandas.stats.api import *

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>()
      7 from pandas.core.common import isnull, notnull
      8 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
----> 9 from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
     10 from pandas.core.format import set_eng_float_format
     11 from pandas.core.index import Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index, Float64Index, MultiIndex

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in <module>()
     15 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject
     16 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
---> 17 from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
     18 from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame
     19 from pandas.core.index import Index, MultiIndex, CategoricalIndex, _ensure_index

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in <module>()
     39                                    create_block_manager_from_arrays,
     40                                    create_block_manager_from_blocks)
---> 41 from pandas.core.series import Series
     42 from pandas.core.categorical import Categorical
     43 import pandas.computation.expressions as expressions

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in <module>()
   2907 # Add plotting methods to Series
   2908 
-> 2909 import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
   2910 
   2911 Series.plot = base.AccessorProperty(_gfx.SeriesPlotMethods, _gfx.SeriesPlotMethods)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in <module>()
    133         return False
    134 
--> 135 if _mpl_ge_1_5_0():
    136     # Compat with mp 1.5, which uses cycler.
    137     import cycler

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py in _mpl_ge_1_5_0()
    128     try:
    129         import matplotlib
--> 130         return (matplotlib.__version__  >= LooseVersion('1.5')
    131                 or matplotlib.__version__[0] == '0')
    132     except ImportError:

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

So if I just try to import pandas:

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

And I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f13a6d5d1db6> in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import division
----> 2 import pandas as pd
      3 import numpy as np

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     11                       "pandas from the source directory, you may need to run "
     12                       "'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C "
---> 13                       "extensions first.".format(module))
     14 
     15 from datetime import datetime

ImportError: C extension: hashtable not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

However, when I check in the python shell, I see this:

```
me-3:python me$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> print pandas.__version__
0.17.1
```

I'm kinda at a loss for what I've done wrong. I think it might be because I have multiple versions of python installed, but I don't quite know what the issue is.

Thanks

Comment: Idle know all path but your system haven't any idea ! Try install panda from source code. Idle not same with python-terminal. (A opinion : `pip` not equal to `apt-get` got a lot differences)

Answer (score 0):

In the Notebook type:

```
In [1]: %ls matplotlib.py
```

If you see a file `matplotlib.py` listed, remove or rename it (using the command line or a tool like a file explorer) and try the import again.